# AngularJS radio button disabled by function if any is selected

Tags: angularjs, radio-button

Still new to AngularJS, can someone explain why i cant get radio button disabled by function?

```
<td class="column" ng-repeat="item in row">
  <input type="radio" name="countries" value="{{item.right}}" id="{{item.name}}" ng-model="answer" ng-disabled="picked(currentIndex)" ng-change="newValue({{item.right}})">
  <label for="{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</label>
</td>
```

Controller:

```
@IndexCtrl = ($scope) ->

  $scope.currentIndex = 0
  $scope.score = 0
  $scope.answered = []

  $scope.picked = (currentIndex) ->
    if $scope.answered.indexOf(currentIndex) is not -1
      return true 
    else
      return false

  $scope.newValue = (value) ->
    $scope.answered.push($scope.currentIndex) if $scope.answered.indexOf($scope.currentIndex) is -1
    ++$scope.score if value
    return
```

Comment: first, remove "{{" and "}}" from newValue({{item.right}})

Comment: Try changing ng-change="newValue({{item.right}})" to ng-change="newValue(item.right)"

Comment: and change picked(currentIndex) to picked($index)

Comment: done, but still not disabling the buttons. Something to do with different $scope perhaps?

Comment: and I think you should use ng-click, not ng-change

Comment: i used ng-click and picked(currentIndex) is inteded as is.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is in coffee script:

```
is not vs isnt (=== ! vs !==)
```

:-)